# How to parse XML file from a server?

Tags: iphone, ios, xml, xml-parsing, nsxmlparser

I've already searched a lot but none of the tutorials and sample codes helped. I am trying to parse a very simple XML data, which will be always the same with just one result, the xml is code bellow:

```
<Books>
    <Book id="1">
        <title>USERS ALREADY EXISTS</title>
    </Book>
</Books>
```

So, how can I parse such a file using `NSXMLParser` or another way you know?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com) Apple's API for parsing XML is [well-documented](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/XMLParsing/XMLParsing.html) and has illustrative [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/SeismicXML/). These won't tell you exactly how to solve your problem for you, but they should familiarize you with the API enough that you can find your way from there, or at least ask more specific questions.

Comment: You can go by Ishu's link also. My method plays with string functions and easy to understand. Adopt whichever you find easy. But you have comprehend it well before you implement. Good luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I parse xml some different way than others and being frank I really do not know which technique it is but I assure you it works fine for me and I have implemeted it successfully in so many projects. Have a look at my code where I load tweets from some [profile](https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=SrBachchan&count=5)

> **This is the function where I make call for parser.**

```
-(void)loadtweet
{
@try
{
    NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.xml?screen_name=SrBachchan&count=5"];

    NSLog(@"fetching data from--------> : %@",urlString);

    NSString* escapedUrlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request1 = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:escapedUrlString]];

    NSURLConnection *con=[[NSURLConnection alloc]  initWithRequest:request1 delegate:self];
    if(con)
        truckData=[[NSMutableData data]retain];
}

@catch (NSException *exception) 
{
    UIAlertView *v = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:@"Please Try Again Later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [v show];
    [v release];
}

}
```

> **And these are the `NSURLConnection` delegate methods:**

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
{
[truckData setLength:0];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data 
{
[truckData appendData:data];
}

- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error 
{

}

- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection 

{
   [tweets removeAllObjects];
 @try 
{
    // [app.trucks removeAllObjects];
    NSString *thexml=[[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:[truckData mutableBytes] length:[truckData length] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSArray *array=[thexml componentsSeparatedByString:@"<status>"];
    NSLog(@"%d",[array count]);

    for(int i=1;i<[array count];i++)
    {
        NSString *str=[array objectAtIndex:i];
        NSArray *arr1=[str componentsSeparatedByString:@"<text>"];
        NSString *data=[arr1 objectAtIndex:1];
        NSRange ranfrom=[data rangeOfString:@"</text>"];
        // nt.truckName=[data substringToIndex:ranfrom.location];
        [tweets  addObject:[data substringToIndex:ranfrom.location]];
    }
}

@catch (NSException *exception) 
{
    UIAlertView *v = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:@"Please Try Again Later." delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [v show];
    [v release];
 }

}
```

I have used some string functions to separate tags and stored the values in Array.

Comment: Just to check,in your code i suppose truckData is a NSMutableArray?And what is tweets,a NSArray too?

Comment: @MateusNunes: Yes. Tweets is NSMutableArray which will hold all your tweets and you will show them in UITableView.. Try putting NSLog and see output you will get to know how these string functions are used.. :-))I will edit my answer and put some comments..:-)